# Scipy Optimizer cannot give the best result

Tags: scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to run a ipynb file which download the data from yahoo and run the scipy optimizer. My objective is to find the optimum weight allocation with the max sharpe ratio.

Link for the ipynb : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fipg3f4kpakm8cj/msr.ipynb?dl=0

```
def msr(riskfree_rate, er, cov):
    n = er.shape[0]
    init_guess = np.repeat(1/n, n)
    bounds = ((0.0, 1.0),) * n 
    # construct the constraints
    weights_sum_to_1 = {'type': 'eq',
                        'fun': lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1
    }
    def neg_sharpe(weights, riskfree_rate, er, cov):
        r = portfolio_return(weights, er)
        vol = portfolio_vol(weights, cov)
        return -(r - riskfree_rate)/vol

    weights = minimize(neg_sharpe, init_guess,
                       args=(riskfree_rate, er, cov), method='SLSQP',
                       options={'disp': False},
                       constraints=(weights_sum_to_1,),
                       bounds=bounds)
    return weights.x
```

And it returns an array of weights

```
array([5.45508083e-13, 2.98622238e-13, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.88124516e-12, 0.00000000e+00])
```

The Sharpe Ratio which I put the riskfree rate = 0

```
ret = weight.T @ annualize_rets(df,period)
vol = (weight.T @ df.cov() @ weight)**0.5
ret/vol
```

Output :

```
-13.779468674840242
```

But I tested with another allocation and it gave a better result

```
test_weight = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1])

test_ret = test_weight.T @ annualize_rets(df,period)
test_vol = (test_weight.T @ df.cov() @ test_weight)**0.5
test_ret/test_vol
```

Output :

```
-12.79174167620581
```

Any problem with the code? Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you confusing minimisation with minimisation of the absolute value? The output it gives seems to be more minimised than the one you give (-13.8 < -12.8)

Comment: I've put a negative sign in front of the formula : return -(r - riskfree_rate)/vol in def neg_sharpe. And therefore it would be able to return the maximum sharpe ratio.

Comment: Have you looked at the full output of the minimize function? Sometimes it will return a result even when there's some soft error which makes it useless for your application